# Bootstrap 2 col not working in mobile view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am working on Bootstrap where I want the two badges closer distance but with my current code it is showing one in right side and other one in left side.

I tried giving the value to left property that is working but the problem is if suppose the first badge size got increase second badge is overlaped with first badge this is happening only in mobile view.

Can some one please suggest me what I am doing wrong here please guide me.

Here is my css code for the badges

```
        .available_badge {
        left: 0% !important;
    }
    .badge-multilet {
        left: 0px !important;
    }
    @media screen and (min-device-width:320px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) {

        .badge-multilet {
            right: 0% !important;
            left: inherit !important;
        }
        .available_badge {
            left: 0% !important;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Code must not be presented as images. Please see [ask].

Comment: Setting left and right values isn't usually a good strategy, especially when working with a layout library. Please provide a proper HTML snippet, along with your CSS, in a working demo using the editor. Add [Bootstrap via CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).

Answer (score -1):

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:480px)
Uses this. media query

Comment: I tried this also but still not working

Comment: @Mr.M use position: absolute.

Comment: position:absolute is there in the parent class @Zeshan

Comment: @Mr.M is this code is live ?

Comment: no it is in my local @Zeshan